# Spiderweb diagramm in Android

Tags: android, diagram

Is there a way to draw spiderweb diagramm in Android to illustrate some data? Something like this:

[image]

I just found something about:

- LineGraphSeries
- BarGraphSeries
- PointsGraphSeries

But they arent that good for my purposes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Mp android chart library ,It is very good lib which provide you spider web chart.

[MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

Comment: oh well its called "radar chart" there, thank you! :)